# Скрипт Google APPS для авторизация нового скрипта, созданного автоматически

Tags: авторизация, google-apps-script, аутентификация, автоматизация

В рамках Google APPS есть проект (javascript) который создает копированием новую таблицу из шаблона. В шаблоне есть свой проект с триггерами и пр. Как вместе с копированием провести программным способом авторизацию вновь созданного проекта. Все происходит на моем аккаунте.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. В этом суть безопасности.

Comment: Т.е. мой авторизированный скрипт не может создать новый скрипт авторизированный мною и для моего аккаунта (т.е. для моих же ресурсов)? Не ужели все так плохо?!

Comment: Автоматически создается новый проект. Они имеет начальные права. Это изменить пока никак невозможно. Я даже не уверен, что возможно автоматически привязать текущий проект к другому. Скорее всего API этого еще не поддерживает.

Comment: Благодарю за  внятный и быстрый ответ. Ни в коей мере не ставлю под сомнение Вашу компетентность и репутацию - они впечатляют. Для полного понимания ситуации разрешите задать вопрос: Это Ваше экспертное мнение, или у Вы пытались решить похожую задачу и потерпели неудачу?

Comment: Я сейчас не могу решить задачу поиска идентификатора контейнера для запущенного скрипта. Это похожие задачи, только я не пытаюсь авторизоваться.  Суть в том, что зная контейнер, по идее можно сделать и обратную задачу - вычислить скрипт в только что созданной Таблице. Но пока никак. Вашу проблему может решить только дополнение или хаки.

Comment: Большое спасибо!